# How to protect a Windows folder without encryption

Tags: windows

How can I protect a folder on Windows without encrypting its contents?

We have an option of creating Windows accounts for different users. But if multiple users are working on the same machine, we would like to prevent access to our `uploads` folder.

Comment: Sorry, you can't.  The way Windows protects user-specific folders is via encryption.

Comment: Not true - see below.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use one folder per user, you can define ACLs on your Windows folders : right click on your folder, choose properties/security and assign some right to your users (Read,Write,...)

Comment: Of course, this doesn't stop anyone that has admin rights.  But it's the best you can do without encryption.